# Clean request.POST object and checking if it is valid

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have the following form in HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type='submit' name='manager_approve' value='{{ leave.leave_id }}' class='btn btn-success btn-md'>Approve</button>
</form>
```

I am processing this request in my view as follows:

```
class ProcessLeaveRequest(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'LMSAdmin/process_leave_request.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'leave_requests': GetLeaves.process_results(request)})

    def post(self, request):

        if 'manager_approve' in request.POST:
            leave = Leaves.objects.get(id=request.POST['manager_approve'])

        return redirect('process_leave_request')
```

Is there a way to run `is_valid()` and `cleaned_data()` functions of `form` class on this `request.POST['manager_approve']` without creating a `form` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `is_valid()` and `cleaned_data` are methods/properties of a `Form` object, so you have to create a form.

But, if you have a model, you could create an instance of that model and run `clean()` to check the attributes are valid, although I don't think this will match your use case since you're only passing an id.

Since your use case is pretty simple, you could avoid the `Form` thing by just catching an exception if there isn't a `Leaves` object with the id passed:

```
try: 
    leave = Leaves.objects.get(id=request.POST['manager_approve'])
except (Leaves.DoesNotExist, ValueError, TypeError):
    # ValueError will be raised if id cannot be cast to int
    # TypeError will be raised if id is of wrong type
    raise Http404
```

Comment: So it is safe to do this without making a form object?

Comment: It wouldn't be safe if you were saving this to the db, but since you're just doing a `get` and using the ORM, Django takes care of casting to int, so there's no need to worry about SQL injection. It would still be cleaner I think to create a simple form with an `IntegerField` and check it's valid.